# Apigility admin screen is not showing my RPC Services

Tags: laminas-api-tools

Not sure what I did and I can't seem to see my RPC Services anymore. They are there and I can see them and get responses to their paths, but I can't see them through the Apigility/Admin screen.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is telling that either the config files are missing or may be even the code itself. When the code is missing normally you see "Unable to fetch code" or similar, so most probably you are missing config files.
It could also be a simple markup problem due to a strange char.

Since the Apigility GUI uses the Apigility API, you can use Firebug to check what is wrong.

Open Firefox and check the tab "Network". Now try to create a service and check the requests, you will probably find a dump with the Exception / Error that you are looking for.

Comment: Well that is definitely a start. I can create services just fine so I am not getting any errors in the network, but when I load the page I am getting errors in  
`76d13e21.vendor.js:5 TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined`
it's an ssue in the apigility included js files: `...vendor.js` It says `Failed to get the list of RPC services`. I am running 1.1, maybe I should just update it?

Comment: Using dev tools did help. I noticed stuff was being flagged and thats how I resolved it. Thank you.